# Can you encode a reflection in a quaternion?

Tags: mathematics, animation, linear-algebra, quaternions

Say we have the transformation:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}

i.e. the matrix that encodes swapping the z and y axes. This is equivalent to a reflection around the z=y line.

Is it possible to encode this same transformation in a quaternion?

Comment: The short answer is: yes. Search for "Quaternion to Matrix" and "Matrix to Quaternion" to get code examples.

Comment: All the vectors in the matrix must be unit length though. But the example you gave they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; quaternions can only represent proper rotations (i.e. without reflection).

If you use non-unit quaternions, you can represent a combination of rotation and uniform scaling, but still not reflection.

Comment: https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/affine/reflection/quaternion/index.htm the math is slightly different for reflections

Comment: It's a non-standard application of quaternions. If you want to change the math, then you can do whatever you want of course. You can represent arbitrary reflections as a scale of (-1, 1, 1) followed by a quaternion rotation, too.

Comment: This isn't inventing new math, and it certainly isn't changing the rules. And this little "trick" can be very handy.

Comment: @pmw1234 it says you can't use them for reflections and rotations simultaneously.